# $p$-group problem

Tags: finite-groups, sylow-theory, p-groups

Let $A,B,C$ are three subgroups in a way that $1<A \triangleleft B \triangleleft C$. With $B/A$ and $C/B$ are $p$-groups. Then prove that $|C|$ is also a $p$-group. I have been trying to prove it for hours but can't find a way to solve it. So any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can't use it because it doesn't say B is the subgroup of C or all it's group is $p-group$. All we can say $C$ is of the form $p^\alpha m$.

Comment: $C$ (not $|C|$ as stated) is a $p$-group here if and only if $A$ is a $p$-group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is false.  Let $A=\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \{0\} \times \{0\}$, $B=\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \{0\}$, and $C=\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$.  $B/A$ and $C/B$ are each isomorphic so $\mathbb{Z}_3$ (so $3$-groups), but $|C|$ is not a power of a prime so $C$ is not a $p$-group for any $p$, let alone $p=3$.

Comment: Yes you are right, I can't believe the question is wrong. I have been trying for hours now. Thank you so much

Comment: Once, I tried for more than a week to prove something.  Finally my advisor said "well have you ever considered that it's actually not true?"  I had the counterexample within 10 minutes :(

Comment: When I was a TA, my professor assigned to his Group Theory students the question:  Assume $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$.  Prove the roots of $f(x)$ form a basis over $\Bbb Q$.  I got 20 different proofs from 20 students, and none of them were right.  I convinced myself of that when I tried for hours to prove it myself.  And then I considered $f(x) = x^2-2$.